# Generate and Renew Let's encrypt cert

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

My domain is (example): mydomain.eu and it’s synchronized with my dynamic IP with np-ip.
In house, I have a web server listening port 80/443 and I got a new wildcard certificate from Let's Encrypt with certbot and deploy with DNS record (txt).

I think that’s enough but no…
I need a certificate for another server (cname mydomain.eu : cloud.mydomain.eu e mail.mydomain.eu) and I set up cname on my provider panel.

Also I set up a cloud server with Nextcloud, and I want to get a certificate for this server.  I get and error because certbot wants 80 and 443 ports, but my Ncserver listens on ports 81 and 1443
In the future, I would create an internal web mail, that listens also another port

Internal setup

```
Example:
WEBSERVER # www.mydomain.eu - nginx - ip xxx.xxx.xxx.50 --> port 80/443
NEXTCLOUD # cloud.mydomain.eu - apache - ip xxx.xxx.xxx.51 -> port 81/1443
MAIL # mail.cloud.mydomain.eu - nginx/apache - ip xxx.xxx.xxx.52 -> port 82/2443
```

Nginx WebServer Configuration:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.eu/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.eu/privkey.pem;

server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name *.mydomain.eu;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name *.mydomain.eu;
root /var/www/html;
index index.html;
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
}

server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name cloud.mydomain.eu;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name cloud.mydomain.eu;

location / {
proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.51:1443;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
}
```

What is the best practice to get certificates for each server ( or a wildcard certificate )?
I would be good activate cron for renew certificates without deploying a `txt` record every three months

Comment: If you are using the [DNS-01 challenge](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#dns-01-challenge), you don't need to run anything on port `80` (that's necessary for the `HTTP-01` challenge). The main question is, whether your DNS provider offers dynamic DNS updates (which **cerbot** can do automatically) or you update the challenge records manually through some sort of web interface. I would guess the second, since you are using no-ip instead of your own domain name.

Comment: If you have already a wildcard certificate you can use the same for your email and cloud subdomain. If everything is on the same server you can use symlinks, if not you can copy your certificate files automatically to your mail and cloud server.

Comment: thanks for your suggest. webserver, cloud and email are in 3 different host ( are Vm with debian) and not in same server. How can i copy certificate filesautomatically? I read it's not safe export private key

Comment: i used this command to generate wildcart cert and i copy acme.challenge on my provider domain (aruba) sudo certbot --email myemail@gmail.com --agree-tos --manual-public-ip-logging-ok certonly --manual --preferred-challenges dns -d 'mydomain.eu,*.mydomain.eu'

Answer (score 1):

in case all the domains are on the same host you can just simply use the same file in the other configuration (you have mentioned wildcard certificate is available)...

It is up to you if you would have one wildcard (re-)used on more services or extra certs per subdomain. Anyway in case you have wildcard cert and it is planned to have it renewed automatically you need anyway DNS token verification (TXT record) and once the domain is validated using DNS you don't need even running server to get the certificate... So in "per domain" cert case you can use DNS verification of the domain so non standard ports are no problem.

Anyway in case of wildcard certificate isn't it easier to have all on standard 80/443 ports ? In these days there is no problem with SNI (sharing the ports and differentiate based on the request content). In that case you can have one reverse proxy (e.g. haproxy) handling wildcard cert and passing traffic to backends (nginx, apache httpd,...)

--- edit - Jan 19 2020 : 22:40 CET ---

In case your DNS provider doesn't offer "easy" dns update you can delegate required "subdomain" to your system and have running local DNS server more or less just for case of this dynamic updates - TXT records...

Let assume domain **example.com** and you local node with updated fqdn **local-example.com.noip.com** pointingn to your system. In the system of the registrar you can do static record:

```
_acme-challenge.example.com. 3600 IN NS local-example.com.noip.com.
```

This way you can easily make delegation for DNS token for example.com domain to your local system. There you can run local DNS server (e.g. bind) with configured domain **_acme-challenge.example.com** where you can then locally update TXT record. Please note that in this domain is not valid record either A nor AAAA so just SOA, NS and dynamic updates at least for TXT ;-).